# Video.js HLS show audio selector on Android devices?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js, hls.js

I made a .m3u8 HLS stream that has multiple audio tracks and use video.js as the player. I already configured my .smil file and it works perfectly on desktop. However, the audio selector disappears when I open it on an Android device.

Does Android support multiple audio tracks streaming? What should I do if I want to have this kind of streaming on Android? Thank you!!

[Player on Android browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHwdF.png)
[Player on Desktop browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WMGy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls#overridenative

Finally managed to select audio in android with this set to true